# Delete cache excluding certain files with javascript

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I'm building my first progressive web application. I'm trying to have delete cache button, is there a way to delete all files excluding certain files & also the ones caches by the service work also.

I seen caches.delete() been used but can i excluding files using that?

delete cache:

```
 self.caches.keys().then(keys => { keys.forEach(key => console.log(key)) })
  self.caches.delete('demo')
```

service worker:

```
var cacheFiles = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/style.css'
];

    self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
      e.waitUntil(
        caches.open("demo").then(function(cache) {
          return cache.addAll(cacheFiles);
        })
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather from your question that you want to delete only certain files from a cache.

I think that's possible, using something like this:

```js
function deleteFileFromCache(fileName, cacheName) {
  caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
    cache.delete(fileName).then(function(response) {
      console.log('cache.delete response:', response);
  }
}
```

At least the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete) imply this will work.